# URL - look through the URL for string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following html menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="About/about-page.html"></a></li>
    <li><a href="Services/services-page.html"></a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I with jQuery check if current URL have string of for example **'About/'** (as 'about' any case + ' / ' ) in it?

Where 'About/' can be any word.

Basically run through my menu and check if there's a string same as the part of the URL.
For example that:

- www.website.com/about/ = true
- www.website.com/about/something.html = true
- www.website.com/about-something.html = false
- www.website.com/services/about.html = false

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "current URL"? An item's URL? Current location URL? Do you want to do it from a selector? Event handler?

Comment: Is the invalid <a> element in your snippet a mistake?

Comment: Current = as currently open website URL

Comment: @Rob Cowie - yep, not relevant anyway:)

Comment: @Pete; Thought so, else I would have fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a variable `currentURL` contains the string you wish to check, and you don't care whether it's got an uppercase 'A' or not:

```
if(currentURL.toLowerCase().indexOf("about") != -1) {
   //Contains 'about'
}
```

If you want to use the URL of the current page:

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;
```

Based on your comment, I think you are trying to apply a class to any `a` element in your list with the word "about" in the `href` attribute. In that case:

```
$("li > a").filter(function() {
   if($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("about") != -1) return true;
   return false;
}).addClass("newClass");
```

**Update** (based on your comments)

You can wrap this in a function that takes the keyword to look for, and the name of the class to add, then call it whenever necessary:

```
function applyClass(keyword, class) {
    $("li > a").filter(function() {
       if($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) != -1) return true;
       return false;
    }).addClass(class);
}
applyClass('service', 'newClass'); //Or for example applyClass('about', 'newClass');
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough. I trying to run through my menu and if found something same as the URL in the menu - addClass to it. As 'About/' can be anything.

Comment: @Pete - I'm not sure if I've understood you fully, but see my updated answer.

Comment: where "about" is the example work - at the moment you will have to write seperate function for word 'service' and so on..  can we try make it within one function? Would 'this.href' work for every word?

Comment: @Pete - See my new update. That should be along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery. Plain old js will do fine:

```
if( window.location.href.indexOf("About/") < 0 )
// Do something!
```

You can also use `window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf` if you want case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery allows selection of elements that have attributes who's value contains a substring

```
$('a[href*="about"]')
```

If you add a 'current' or 'active' class to the 'currently selected' nav menu item, you might use the following selector:

```
$('a.active[href*="about"]')
```

**EDIT:**

Reading some of your comments, I think perhaps what you need is to find any nav item that matches the current url. So...

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]');
```

Change `window.location.pathname` accordingly if your hrefs are fully qualified. See http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location for window.location attributes.